# How to make bootable ISO from modified Debian 11

Tags: linux, iso-image

I have modified a Debian 11 system. I want to make a bootable installation ISO for it. I have used Systemback and Linux Live Kit already, but the file they generate exceeds 4GB. What do I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Modified how exactly? If you intend to use this ISO on systems with varying non-free firmware, I expect that will cause you headaches. I would instead suggest creating a post installation build script - this is a future proof approach, that will work across all possible platforms/architectures, is eternally editable/customisable, and will only cost you kilobytes of storage, not gigabytes... It's how I build all of my debian systems (4 in total, all different hardware).

Comment: Well its basically aimed at creating a custom OS without actually building the kernel stuff, and as far as custom OS goes, i don't believe a post install script is the number one approach